# Liquid neon freezer?

Tags: phase, liquids

Liquid nitrogen is approximately -330 degrees Fahrenheit. Liquid neon is approximately -413 degrees Fahrenheit. I want to know about if this type of freezer is easily possible in practice and if such a freezer actually exists. The idea is to keep the matter as cold as possible and combine it with a noble element that doesn’t react with anything that we know of due to electron configuration. The idea of liquid neon is to stop effectively all biological activity and chemical reactions, because liquid nitrogen is both hotter and not a noble gas, though liquid neon is not a noble *gas* though neon usually is.

Comment: What's the point? Liquid nitrogen is quite enough to stop all biological activity and _nearly_ all chemical reactions, and itself is quite inert at these temperatures. In the rare cases where you genuinely need to go lower, helium is your choice.

Comment: We should note that some chemical species have only been observed in matrix isolation. However, one typically uses argon (because it is commonly available) or helium (because the lower temperature is needed). One could suppose the use of neon for reactions at temperatures higher than liquid/solid helium that also necessitate a matrix more inert than argon.

Comment: Neon has the advantage that it has about [$20\times$](https://periodictable.com/Properties/A/VaporizationHeat.an.html) the molar specific heat of helium, so that even if it doesn't get things as cold it can cool them off quicker. The huge disadvantage is that neon is much more expensive than helium or nitrogen.

Comment: Liquid nitrogen is probably sufficient, but neon is both more inert and colder/less hot.

Comment: I'd suspect that liquid neon would be significantly more expensive than liquid nitrogen with scant reduction in chemical reactivity and scant further reduction in biological activity.

Comment: Just because it is slight doesn’t mean it doesn’t happen

Comment: You're really not talking about a self-contained "freezer" but a cryostat where a liquid coolant will need frequent replenishment.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. By "scant reduction" I mean yes there is a theoretical reduction but that the reduction is in reality so small as to be immeasurable. // Excess isn't always better. Ever try to park a semi-truck in a typical parking garage for cars?

Comment: Makes sense, so nitrogen is probably sufficient